# How do I put an IF condition in my MySQL WHERE clause using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to use if conditions of php in mysql where clause. I have a problem in my program ,the thing is i need to select the all user photos ,if the visitor of the site is friend to that person then we need to display few images, if not a friend dont to display the images.

finally i need to check the image creator id with visitor id if they are friends are not then proceed the query, All this required in a single query

Comment: It`s nice if you kindly post a code snippet of what you have tried so far.  Maybe just the sql query you are trying to pull data from, the table structure also helps on sql related questions.

Comment: you better tell what you want to fetch and how you want to fetch data from database with example.. 
you can not use PHP if condition in MYSQL the way you use in PHP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The very first thing you should write after "a problem", "an error", or "exception" is the **exact** problem code, error description, or exception message. "I have a problem in my program" provides absolutely no information that we can use to help you solve it. If you think it is, call your doctor and say "I don't feel well. What's wrong?" and see if the doctor will diagnose you and prescribe a treatment. Please remember we can't see your screen from here, and the only info we have to help you is what you provide in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need dynamically changing mysql query. Try something like this
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tablename." WHERE ".$this->fieldid."="."'".$this->id."'";`                    WHere fieldid and id will change according to what you pass through your php page

Comment: No actually i need to check the field value with visitor user id ,if the condition passes then i need to write some where clause ,or if condition fails i need to write some other where clause, these two are dependent on the first if condition ,and all in one query,that is the problem

Comment: See i think you cannot write if condn in mysql query as pointed above, So you need you pass values depending according to your if condn.

Comment: table name :community_notes 
fileds  :id,title,subject,description,published,creator,tags,permissions,created,status


and i am having a connect table where it states the users connection

table name :user_connection 
filelds    :id,connect_from,connect_to,status 
 
My requirement is to select all the records from the table,

if condtion
the site visitor user id is a friend with notes creator 
then select all records where permissions =0 or 10,20

if not a friend 
then select all records where permissions =0

 
this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

it just an idea to part the query like:

```
$query = "select * from tbl_name where";
if(condition){
  ...
$query .= "your query";
}

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: table name :community_notes 
fileds  :id,title,subject,description,published,creator,tags,permissions,created,status


and i am having a connect table where it states the users connection

table name :user_connection 
filelds    :id,connect_from,connect_to,status 
 
My requirement is to select all the records from the table,

if condtion
the site visitor user id is a friend with notes creator 
then select all records where permissions =0 or 10,20

if not a friend 
then select all records where permissions =0

Answer (score 0):

> All this required in a single query

This is wrong erequirement.
There are no such a [sane] limitation.
Always use whatever number of queries that required by the task. No more and no less.

You could show your queries and ask if there is a way to reduce the number, for sake of more sensible code.